On the sheaves-functions dictionary
Let $X$ be a variety over a finite field $k$. Let $\pi_{1}(X)$ be the arithmetic etale fundamental group of $X$, and $\rho:\pi_{1}(X)\to k^{\times}$ a continuous character. If $x: \text{Spec}(k)\to X$ is a $k$-point, then it induces a map $\pi_1(\text{Spec}(k))\to \pi(X)$, and the geometric Frobenius element in $\pi_{1}(\text{Spec}(k))$ defines an image $F_x$ in $\pi_{1}(X)$. In this way, we obtain the trace function $t_{\rho}:X(k)\to k^{\times},x\mapsto \rho(F_{x}) $, and a map
$$T:\{\rho:\pi_1(X)\to k^{\times}\}\to \text{Map}(X(k),k^{\times}),~\rho \mapsto t_{\rho},$$
where the left hand side is the set of continuous $k$-valued characters of $\pi_{1}$ and the right hand side is the set of $k^{\times}$-valued functions on $X(k)$. My question is the following:

When is the map $T$ surjective?

The answer is positive when $X$ is a connected commutative algebraic group over $k$ because the Lang isogeny $X\to X$ is a finite, etale, Galois covering with Galois group $X(k)$, and hence there exists a natural sujection $\pi_{1}(X)\to X(k)$.

The answer is not necessarily positive in the case you give because you are demanding $\rho$ be a character, i.e. a group homomorphism, but the natural surjection $\pi_1(X) \to X(k)$ composed with an arbitrary map $X(k) \to k^\times$ does not give a group homomorphism. In fact for $X$ an abelian variety a function $X(k) \to k^\times$ comes from $\pi_1$ if and only if it is a homomorphism (for the natural group law on $X(k)$) times a constant function.

You really mean to take the values of the functions in the same field as the varieties are defined over? This is very atypical for the sheaf-functions dictionary. If so, then the same is true for any connected commutative algebraic group, as the relevant characters of $\pi_1$ are forced to be tame since $k^\times$ is prime-to-$p$.
